# create continuous snake like slither.io MonoGame c#

Tags: c#, game-design, monogame, game-mechanics

I need help creating a snake with continuous smooth motion like slither.Io up till now I just can't find any but the grid snake.

**EDIT:** Following a curve with the snake, Grow that snake.

Comment: What is your specific problem with this, what have you attempted for yourself as of asking this question?

Comment: I got no idea about the mechanic of an elastic snake like this.

Comment: Beside http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445164/create-snake-like-slither-io-monogame    you know ? I hate this last part of your answer.

Comment: Do you want help with the steering controls, the movement and acceleration of boosts, growth, or following bezier curves/splines? You have to ask one specific question that we can help you solve. It's difficult to help you out if you haven't attempted a quick go at building this and coming to us with a non-working first attempt solution.

Comment: following bezier curves/splines that's it :D

Comment: Bros , Should I post the code for anyone looking for same question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, in slither.io, the snake isn't following a spline at all. Each segment simply follows the previous segment.

So create a head and a bunch of segments. The head is just a special segment with your movement and other logic in it:

```
class SnakeHead:SnakeSegment
{
   List<SnakeSegment> Body = new List<SnakeSegment>(); //keep the bodyparts here so we can update them easily

   //do your steering logic etc here.
}
class SnakeSegment
{
   Vector2 Position;
   SnakeSegment Parent;
}
```

Then create the snake:

```
    SnakeHead Snake = new SnakeHead();
    SnakeHead.Position = new Vector2(100,100);

    SnakeSegment parentsegment = Snake;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // 10 segements seems okay.
    {
        SnakeSegment bodypart = new SnakeSegment();
        SnakeSegment.Position = parentsegment.Position;
        SnakeSegment.Parent = parentsegment;

        Snake.Body.Add(bodypart); // add the bodypart to the list
        parentsegment = bodypart; // remember this one for the next bodypart.
    }
```

So each segment does something like the following:

```
void Update()
{ 
    if(Vector2.Distance(parent.Position,this.Position)>_minDistanceBetweenSegments)
    {
        Vector2 Orientation = (Parent.Position - this.Position).Normalize();
        this.Position += Orientation * _followSpeed;
    }
}
```

This checks if the head is further away from the previous segment than you want (`_minDistanceBetweenSegments`); if it is, move it into the direction of the previous segment. If the `_followSpeed` is equal to the movement speed of the head, the snake will trail instantly. Due to the `Orientation` the snake will flow nicely as in the Slither.io game.

So have the head loop through the bodysegments, and call update in those segments and you're set.

(code is untested; just for illustrating how the effect of a segmented trailing snake works)

Comment: Thanks , I got the sank to work ! By the way in orientation must be normalized()

Comment: http://pictub.club/image/Vr0yr
http://pictub.club/image/VrZfk
http://pictub.club/image/Vr81x